# How signal interrupt works for getline() in C?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have a minimal working code which is suppose to read user input and handle any SIGINT (ctrl+c). I used [sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). If ctrl+c is pressed, it will print a `$` on the new line and wait for user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigint_received = 0;

static void handler(int signum)
{
    sigint_received = 1;
}


int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n = 100;
    line = malloc(n);

    while(1){
        if(sigint_received){
            sigint_received = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("$ ");
        getline(&line, &n, stdin);

        if(!strcmp(line, "exit\n")){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(line){
        free(line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I does what is intended (accidentally). My question is after OS handle the interrupt how come `getline` doesn't wait for the input? Should't the program resume from where it was left off?

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not good at linux programming, so sorry if this is a noob question.</sub>

Comment: `getline` should return -1, and set `errno` to `EINTR`, if ctrl+c is pressed before any characters have been read. So as a minimum, the code should be checking the return value from `getline`.

Comment: If you set `sa.sa_flags` to `SA_RESTART` it will be restarted after the interrupt.

Comment: @EmanuelP You are right! Where is this on the man page? They should have mentioned it.

Comment: @hacks The [do](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). It's common behavior with many functions that use a system call underneath the hood.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you provide some more details and put it in an answer?

Comment: @EmanuelP That man page has not explained it well. I read `man sigaction` on my system and it does say about this specifically: *"SA_RESTART      See paragraph below."* and then, ....

Comment: You're also not checking the return value from `getline()`.  If you were to start with `line = NULL` and `getline()` were to return `-1` after being interrupted, with `line` still equal to `NULL` you'd probably `SIGSEGV` on the `strcmp()` call.

Comment: *If a signal is caught during the system calls listed below, the call may be forced to terminate with the error `EINTR`, the call may return with a data transfer shorter than requested, or the call may be restarted.  Restart of pending calls is requested by setting the `SA_RESTART` bit in `sa_flags`.  The affected system calls include `open(2)`, `read(2)`, `write(2)`, `sendto(2)`, `recvfrom(2)`, `sendmsg(2)` and `recvmsg(2)` on a communications channel or a slow device (such as a terminal, but not a regular file) and during a `wait(2)` or `ioctl(2)`. ...*

Comment: @hacks I agree the manuals could be clearer on this.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Correct! Now I understood. I should have checked the system man page of `getline` along with the `sigaction`.

Comment: On my system, the manual entry for `getline` says *"These functions may also fail due to any of the errors specified for fgets() and malloc()."*, and the manual entry for `fgets` says *"The function fgets() may also fail and set errno for any of the errors specified for the routines fflush(3), fstat(2), read(2), or malloc(3)"*. It's the man page for `read` that documents `EINTR`. So the only lesson here is to always read about the return value from a function, and then follow all the links to find to all the error numbers. Ignoring the return value is never acceptable.

Comment: @user3386109 Can't agree more.

Comment: @haccks Good job. Tbh, I knew this, but I was digging through the manuals to write you an answer because it is very scattered.

Comment: @EmanuelP It is scattered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) and [@Emanuel P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15381660/emanuel-p) for their insightful comments. I checked man page of `sigaction` and `getline` on Mac and this is what I found:

`man sigaction`:

> SA_RESTART See paragraph below.

and then

> *If a signal is caught during the system calls listed below, the call may be forced to terminate with the error `EINTR`, the call may return with a data transfer shorter than requested, or the call may be restarted.  Restart of pending calls is requested by setting the `SA_RESTART` bit in `sa_flags`.  The affected system calls include `open(2)`, `read(2)`, `write(2)`, `sendto(2)`, `recvfrom(2)`, `sendmsg(2)` and `recvmsg(2)` on a communications channel or a slow device (such as a terminal, but not a regular file) and during a `wait(2)` or `ioctl(2)`. ...*

And `getline` does return `-1` on failure. And it says [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> In the event of a failure, `errno` is set to indicate the error.

In this case `errno` will be set to `EINTR` as pointed in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586236/handling-sigint-signal-with-sigaction-in-c#comment133354222_75586236).

After handling the interrupt program will resume from `getline` and will not wait for user input. Instead, as mentioned above it will terminate with the error `EINTR`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigint_received = 0;

static void handler(int signum)
{}


int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n = 100;
    line = malloc(n);

    while(1){  
        printf("$ ");
        ssize_t ret = getline(&line, &n, stdin);

        if(ret == -1 && errno == EINTR){
            printf("\n");
            errno = 0;  // Reset errno flag
            continue;
        }

        if(!strcmp(line, "exit\n")){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(line){
        free(line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline()` can fail for other reasons. Best to check for `EINTR` explicitly. ```if (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR) { continue; }```

Comment: @Haris; In that case do I need to `clearerr(stdin);` to reset the `errno`?

Comment: **The `clearerr()` function shall not change the setting of errno if
 stream is valid."** ====> A simple `errno = 0;` before the call to `getline()` would do.

Comment: @Haris I read you should never change `errno` manually.

Comment: It  is perfectly fine, even necessary, to set it to 0 before calling some functions. For instance, this is what the POSIX specification says: ***"Since 0, {LONG_MIN} or {LLONG_MIN}, and {LONG_MAX} or {LLONG_MAX} are returned on error and are also valid returns on success, an application wishing to check for error situations should set errno to 0, then call strtol() or strtoll(), then check errno. [Option End]."***